# C++ a multiple indexes map

Tags: c++, dictionary

I am implementing a simple searching systems where all the data are stored in the memory of the running process.

Originally, I plan to use a map of tuple to achieve this.

```
map<tuple<int, string, ...>, string> dict
```

However, it is only working when all the keys are known and not missing.

For example, say, I have,
map<<key1, key2, key3, key4, key5>, value> dict;

I cannot search the map without key2 or key2 is "don't care"

Is there any standard lib or function in C++ to do that?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: No, there's nothing in the C++ library like that. And it is technically impossible to do anything of that sort, neither with a map nor any other associative container in the C++ library, for a number of fundamental reasons. You will have to design and implement your own container that uses separate maps/unordered_maps for each key.

Comment: Honest question, but have you considered using a relational database? That would make it much easier to make arbitrary queries and they are built to handle the indexing and storage for you.

Comment: No, it is not intended to use a database due to the requirement.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::map<int, std::map<string, std::map< ... , string > ... > > dict;
```

You can "not care" at any step.  You do have to check *every* possibility there.

You can do a combinatorial explosion to do all n! orderings, and have everything point to either a shared pointer or something similar.

This isn't cheap.

Permute the arguments in every possibility (n!), then make a map from each tuple of augmented optionals (with a min and max state) to the same shared ptr of data.  You can now do an ordering that treats either the left or the right as least significant, and use `equal_range` to not care about that key.

You could instead make an attack using something like a quad tree or oct tree or n-tree structure.  That does multi-dimensional "sorting".  Getting that to work with arbitrary keys will be fun.

Comment: Instead of permuting the arguments in every possibility, maybe can consider to have something like map<key1, vector<shared_ptr<value>>>, map<key2, vector<shared_ptr<value>>>, map<key3, vector<shared_ptr<value>>>, etc.

Then, let say, I only specify key1 and key3 (without key2), I can search the key1 and key3 maps, then compare the vector<shared_ptr<value>> to take the intersection set

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting and nontrivial problem I happen to have studied some years ago:

- The problem is, given *n* keys, to be able to efficiently  query for an arbitrary subset of those keys.
- In DB terminology, this can be solved by creating *m* indices so that each combination of keys is covered by some index. The problem is described [here](http://bannalia.blogspot.com/2008/10/multicolumn-querying.html): the number of indices is *C*(*n*,floor(*n*/2)), where *C*(*a*,*b*) is the binomial coefficient [*a* choose *b*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialCoefficient.html). for *n*=5, the number of required indices is *m*=10.
- I devised [an algorithm](http://bannalia.blogspot.com/2008/10/generating-permutation-covers-part-ii.html) for determining what the actual indices are. In the case of *n*=5 and keys *a*, *b*, *c*, *d*, *e*, you can use indices *(acedb),(baedc),(bdaec),(bedca),(cbaed),(cdbae),(cebad),(daceb),(decab),(eadbc)*. A crucial aspect here is that indices can be used for *shorter* combinations of keys. For instance, *(acedb)* covers the following (rearranged in alphabetical order): *(a),(ac),(ace),(acde),(abcde)*. This is the reason why you can cover any combination with only 10 indices instead of 2<sup>5</sup>−1=31.
- Now, Boost.MultiIndex can be used to actually specify and use these indices. There's an [example](http://bannalia.blogspot.com/2008/11/multiattribute-querying-with.html) with 4 keys that you can extend easily to 5 keys if so you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You asked:

> Is there any standard lib or function in C++ to do that?

The answer to that question is *No*.

The requirements are a little vague, because it seems you have a particular interface in mind. You should define your interfaces, and what you expect them to do.

The implementation of a `find()` like function with don't cares could be implemented with a multiple index data structure. Roughly:

- Create a container (like a `set`) of all your records.
- For each key field, create a `map` associating values in that key field to a `set` of iterators in the `set` of records.
- A `find` method would walk the collection of key `map`s, and compute intersections of the returned `set`s of iterators.

Comment: This seems the similar idea I just replied in the previous solution. That is to create a map for each key field

Answer (score 0):

Not in `std`, but there is [`boost::multi_index`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html), which allows you to specify arbitrary projections of you data as keys, and you can have as many as you like.

```
// your keys and value
struct Datum {
    key1_t key1;
    key2_t key2;
    key3_t key3;
    // etc ...
    value_t value;
};

namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;

// some unique types
struct Key1 {};
struct Key2 {};
struct Key3 {};
struct Key1Key2 {};
struct Key1Key2Key3 {};

using Dict = boost::multi_index_container<Datum, bmi::indexed_by<
    bmi::ordered_unique<bmi::tag<Key1>, bmi::key<&Datum::key1>>, // just key 1
    bmi::ordered_unique<bmi::tag<Key2>, bmi::key<&Datum::key2>>, // just key 2
    bmi::ordered_unique<bmi::tag<Key3>, bmi::key<&Datum::key3>>, // just key 3
    bmi::ordered_unique<bmi::tag<Key1Key2>, bmi::key<&Datum::key1, &Datum::key2>>, // key 1 then key 2
    bmi::ordered_unique<bmi::tag<Key1Key2Key3>, bmi::key<&Datum::key1, &Datum::key2, &Datum::key3>>, // key 1 then key 2 then key 3
>;
int main() {
    Dict dict = /* stuff */

    key1_t key1 = /* stuff */
    key2_t key2 = /* stuff */
    key3_t key3 = /* stuff */

    auto it1 = dict.get<0>().find(key1); // select which by position
    auto it2 = dict.get<Key2>().find(key2); // or by the tag types 
    auto it5 = dict.get<Key1Key2Key3>().find({ key1, key2, key3 }); // multiple keys
}
```

Comment: It seems good, but from your code, it looks like that I need to specify all the combinations of keys? I mean if I have 10 keys (or even more), there are too many.